# Stylize Google Sign-in Button in React for new Google Identity Services

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, google-oauth, mern

How to stylize a google sign-in button in React with the new Google Identity Services. The SDK uses sign in with google Client library.

I dont want to change the way the button looks but I want to move it to the centre of the page or a particular coordinate. I tried using align-centre, change back-ground colour etc.. for the  in which the Sign-in button resides but of no use. All the other JSX elements inherit the style except the google button which stays at the left end of the page.

Here is the Login.js component which hosts the google sign-in button.

```
import {GoogleLogin} from "@react-oauth/google";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
const Login = () => {
    const history=useHistory();
    const handleResponse=(credentialresponse)=> {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/login',{
            method:'POST',
            credentials:'include',
            mode:'cors',
            headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
            body:JSON.stringify(credentialresponse)
        })
        .then(response=>{
            history.push('/catlist');
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log('eror',err));
    }
    const handleError=()=>{
        console.log("Error Logging in");
    }

    return ( 
        <div className="login-page">

            <h1>Login With Google</h1>
            <GoogleOAuthProvider 
                clientId="my_client_id_goes_here">
                <GoogleLogin onSuccess={handleResponse} onError={handleError}/>
            </GoogleOAuthProvider>;
           
            
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Login;
```